# Swap 2 lines within a JSON file. Lat and Lon without tags

Tags: python, node.js, json

I have a large json file with code that looks a lot like below. I wish to have the same output but need the latitude and longitude swapped.

```
"path": [
        [
            -0.662301763628716,
            51.48792441079866
        ],
        [
            -0.661955225774188,
            51.487855733392
        ],
        [
            -0.66143913564835,
            51.48772120562989
        ]
```

The goal is to swap these 2 numbers around, they vary as they are GPS latitude and longitude values. Any solution using programs/language script is welcome.

Edit:

After the answers that have been posted on this, I have come to provide additional details. It would appear since the path is encased further it does not allow it to be `.reservse. as well as I would have hoped.

Here is the full format -

```
[
    {
        "name": "Dedworth West",
        "path": [
            [
                -0.662301763628716,
                51.48792441079866
            ],
            [
                -0.661955225774188,
                51.487855733392
            ],
            [
                -0.66143913564835,
                51.48772120562989
            ],
```

Comment: The key 'path' has a value which is a list of lists. Just iterate over each sub-list and swap the contents of index 0 with index 1

Comment: just work with what you got. Swapping seems pointless as long as you document which one is which and use it that way.

Comment: @TheFool A GeoJSON file needs the order Lon Lat, rather than Lat Lon

Comment: @TomMcLean, if its *invalid* how was it created in the first place? Should maybe look at the root of the evil here and create it property from the beginning, or file an issue with the code / API that did it. If it's really a well-defined standard, something is not conforming.

Comment: @TheFool There are many geographic standards, ISO 6709 expects Lat Lon, the GeoJSON format expects Lon Lat.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_6709#Items

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7946#section-3.1.1

Comment: He may be getting data from one source, and then plotting it in GeoJSON which requires a different order...

Comment: I do not see geojson in the question anywhere, but maybe you are right.

Answer (score 2):

Say your json looked like:

```
j = {"path": [
        [
            -0.662301763628716,
            51.48792441079866
        ],
        [
            -0.661955225774188,
            51.487855733392
        ],
        [
            -0.66143913564835,
            51.48772120562989
        ]]}
```

You can reverse each list in place:

```
from typing import List

def reverse(l: List):
    l.reverse()
```

and apply it to the json in place:

```
map(reverse, j["path"])
```

And now the json looks like:

```
{'path': [[51.48792441079866, -0.662301763628716], [51.487855733392, -0.661955225774188], [51.48772120562989, -0.66143913564835]]}
```

p.s. I don't like doing stuff in place, but its the way the `.reverse` function works...

Comment: @chitown88 Im not sure I like it aha. I really hate doing stuff in place with lists, can cause bugs. It's probably quite fast though...

Comment: I'm also not sure why `map(list.reverse, j['path'])` doesnt work

Comment: `map(list.reverse, j['path'])` doesn't work because map puts each list as argument into the supplied function.  As you demonstrate yourself. List.reverse doesn't take an argument but reverses the lists its being called on.

Comment: `map(lambda l: l.reserve(), j['path'])` would be an option to keep it a one liner.

Comment: @TheFool Yeah I tried that, didnt work for me?

Comment: Using a lambda here is formally equivalent to your solution. I don't see how one would work but the other one not. Whats suspiocus about both ways it that you dont return anything. l.reverse doesnt return the result as it mutates the list, but map wants to assign the return value. So both are actually somewhat misuse of map. Still not sure why one works, the other not. Could be that lambda has an implicit return statement and a regular function not, but I am not 100% on this.

Comment: ah good point. This is actually very helpful actually

Comment: A one liner solution would be `j['path'][:] = map(lambda l: list(reversed(l)), j['path'])`

Comment: Seems I was not detailed enough in my question. This approach is being well received but I am getting the error due to my own fault.

```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "convert.py", line 1, in <module>
    j = {[
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

The format is more like :

```[
    {
        "name": "Dedworth West",
        "path": [
            [
                -0.662301763628716,
                51.48792441079866
            ],
``` which doesn't work in the lists.

Comment: After addition testing I have got the list to a point where this is the error `TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str`.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through and just swap them by their index.

```
data = {"path": [
        [
            -0.662301763628716,
            51.48792441079866
        ],
        [
            -0.661955225774188,
            51.487855733392
        ],
        [
            -0.66143913564835,
            51.48772120562989
        ]]}

dataSwap = {'path':[]}
for x in data['path']:
    dataSwap['path'].append([x[-1], x[0]])
```